# Is it possible to add some vertical space like ~~~?

Tags: spacing, xy-pic

I sometimes uses `~` to adjust space between symbols. Now I want to add some vertical space which play similar role, how do I do that?

(It's not about controlling space between lines, but just add some space, the real problem is like this: I put `\displaystyle \int X`, and `X` at the same time in an `xymatrix`, then the arrows are of different length because it thinks `\displaystyle \int X` occupied more vertical space than `X`.
)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to make Xy-pic think that the node with just `X` takes up the same vertical space as `\displaystyle\int X`, you can use a `\vphantom`.  For example, if you type

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{displaymath}
  \xymatrix{
    \displaystyle \int X \ar[r] \ar[d]
    & {\vphantom{\displaystyle \int}X} \ar[d]\\
    {A} \ar[r]
    & {B}
  }
\end{displaymath}
\end{document}
```

then you'll get

[image]